# php strtotime get next specific date

Tags: php, date, strtotime

Using `strtotime` or the `DateTime` constructor, is there any way to get php to tell me the next time a *specific* date will occur?

Let's say I want the next time it will be August 3rd. I want to be able to say something like "next August 3rd" to be able to get "August 3rd, 2016". (currently that bombs out with `Failed to parse time string (next August 3rd)`) Or "next July 19th", which would be "July 19th, 2017". Currently, I have to figure out if the date has passed or not, and then adjust the year accordingly.

**Can the string to date parser handle this somehow?**

Comment: Have you read this? http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php. Month names are not mentioned there, so the answer is probably 'no'.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but '3rd day of August' may work. Although it may always use the current year even if the date has passed, test it and see.

Comment: write your own function. fetch the month and day from your statement. Then, check if it's passed by the current year, go for next year. otherwise, go for current year.

Comment: @vascowhite "3rd day of April" bombs out, "April 3/3rd" uses current year